# spring-jdbc doesn't seem to work with spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring-boot

I'm following along the 15 min guide for sprint-boot ([gs-relational-data-access](http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/))

As such the guide works which uses H2-database.
So now I'm changing that to use DB2 by providing the jars at runtime.

Modified build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Now application fails complaining JdbcTemplate bean definitions not found or something along the lines.

So now I further modified the build.gradle to comment out the spring-jdbc, and use spring-boot-starter-jdbc

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    //compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Now the application works again. I'm interested in knowing why the spring-jdbc dependency didn't work with just the sprint-boot-starter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spring-jdbc` has all classes that spring support for JDBC API but `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` allow to enable all the auto-configuration needed. Thanks to the auto-configuration you can autowired `JdbcTemplate` and `JdbcOperations` with a simple configuration in application.properties